# Render entry_id in URL from jquery

Tags: url, jquery, table

I've made a little script to be able to select entire rows in a table.

```
$(".clickableRow").on("click", function() {
    location.href="{path='leerlijnen/school/{entry_id}/#toevoegen'}";
});
```

However the href doesn't produce a valid URL: ../leerlijnen/school/{entry_id/#toevoegen'}   where I expected: ../leerlijnen/school/3964/#toevoegen.

Any glues?

Comment: Are you running this in your channel entries tags?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
../leerlijnen/school/{entry_id}/#toevoegen
```

You may have to put it between channel tags to get it to parse.